# Migration category / section in to the joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, migration, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I want to migrate Category / Section of Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5. But Joomla 2.5 has not section option.

My old Joomla 1.5 website has more then 300 sections are there. I have migrate website form Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5 using sp upgrade. But section are not migrate in Joomla 2.5.

How can i use those section in new version web. May I have to create Sub Category for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a good migratiion tool (I use SPUpgrade,) you'll be given the option of bringing in the sections, which just become categories.

Comment: You mean to say that sections are react as sub category in Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 4):

In Joomla 2.5 all sections are consider as categories. So add all sections in category modules.  That will work fine.